# Use AngularJS to stylize a label when the text input field is changed

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've searched for how to do this, and I've not had any luck.  I'm fairly inexperienced with web stuff, so perhaps it's so trivial that no one needs to ask how to do it :(

Suppose I have an HTML text input field with a label, like this:

```
<label for = "stuff">Stuff</label>
<input type = "text" name = "stuffz" id="stuff" value = "hello!">
```

Now suppose the text input field value is changed.  Is there a way to use AngularJS to restyle the label (Like, turn it green, for example) when this change occurs?  I've looked into using ng-change and ng-class, but I'm not knowledgeable enough about how these work to use them in this manner.

Any help would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ngClass` and `ngChange` :

```js
angular.module('demo', []);
```

```css
.marvellous {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo">

<label for="stuff"
       ng-class="{ 'marvellous' : !!hasChanged }">
  Stuff
</label>
<input type="text"
       id="stuff"
       ng-model="myModel"
       ng-change="hasChanged = true">
  
</div>
```